# Button style with image

Tags: button, javafx-2

I was wondering How one can achieve following button style where text resides underneath of image in JavaFx?

I tried a lot but all in vain. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is the `contentDisplay` property, set it to "TOP".

With fxml:

```
<Button contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
  <graphic>
    <ImageView mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="@image.png" preserveRatio="false" smooth="false" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
  </graphic>
</Button>
```

Or CSS:

```
.your-selector {
    -fx-content-display: top;
}
```

Check the CSS reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve that just by doing

```
    Button b = new Button("text", graphics);
    b.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
```

And for cool icons, take a look at http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/ it include icone from [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/)

Comment: Sorry I downvoted accidentally ... the only way I have found to cancel the downvote is to have you edit your post first (Just add a dot). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139949/unable-to-undo-downvote